# Form Auto Submit on page load in Same Page Once jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I created one form in PHP and I want to submit this form on the same page using jQuery. for this, I added the jQuery javascript code:-

This is working but my problem is that this loading page, again and again, infinite, because my Form is submitted on the same page.

```js
 
  window.onload = function () {
   document.getElementById("wcv_stores_radial_search").submit();
   }
```

```html
<form action="" method="POST" id="wcv_stores_radial_search" name="wcv_stores_radial_search" class="standard-form">

<input type="text" size="40" id="wcv_stores_location" name="wcv_stores_location" placeholder="" value="ABC" />


</form>
```

Please give me a solution what i do for that, and if this is possible using AJAX then what will i used for AJAX code.

Comment: When should the form be sent? When the value of the `<select>` changes? Then you should listen to `onchange`. Currently, your form will be sent as soon as the page is loaded (`onload`), this makes no sense.

Comment: No, I have one more form on another page when I submit that form I pass it's query string value on that form, so the user can't select for fill value on that form.

Comment: Like previous comment stated it makes no sense what you are saying. Your on load is trying to send wcv_stores_radial_search value witch you haven't yet set. Be more clear about what your goal is.

Comment: Now I remove the select field, I only want that if a user comes on the page then this form auto submit.

Answer (score 0):

you should cread a hidden input with a variable and if that variable was true the script exit before it reloads

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).